# How to refresh a local pip cache

Tags: python, pip

Given a pip requirements file, how do you update a local cache of Python packages **without** installing anything or unnecessarily re-downloading packages that are currently up to date?

I've tried:

```
pip install --download="packages" --exists-action=w -r pip-requirements.txt
```

However, it seems to automatically redownload everything, even if the correct version has already been downloaded. How do I prevent this?

Also, what's the difference between `--download=DIR` and `--download-cache=DIR`? The docs aren't very clear, and provided descriptions sound almost identical. It seems implied that specifying `--download=DIR` does not install anything whereas specifying `--download-cache=DIR` may or may not install anything.

Answer (score 4):

I think that `pip install -r pip-requirements.txt` is all you need, as usually pip doesn't redownload already installed packages.

Even if you do `pip install --upgrade -r pip-requirements.txt` I would expect it only to upgrade those that needed to be.

Are you workign inside a `virtualenv`?  That could be your problem.

Comment: It's definitely re-downloading everything. And no, I'm not using a virtualenv, although I've tested it with one and found the behavior to be the same.

Comment: It might help if you post some of what pip is showing as it starts to re-download.

Comment: @Cerin: make sure you have a recent version of pip. Try `pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted, especially when no else provided an answer of any kind.